# How to select button in UICollectionViewCell and retrieve state for another action in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uicollectionview, cell

I have two buttons in a uicollectioncell and want to select one and then perform an action on the other depending on the state of the first button.
I have tried this but it throws up : "swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
func firstAction(sender:UIButton) {
    var cell = Customcell()
    cell.firstButton.selected = true
    cell.firstButton.selected = !cell.firstButton.selected
}

@IBAction func secondAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var cell = CustomCell()
    if cell.firstButton.selected == true {
        // DO stuff....
    } else {
        println("No button selected")
    }
}
```

I set the button in cellForItemAtIndexPath like this:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
cell.firstButton.addTarget(self, action: "firstAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
cell.secondButton.addTarget(self, action: "secondAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: here : cell.firstButton.selected = true

Comment: I guess `firstButton` is an `IBOutlet`? If you instantiate your cell manually, the nib won't be loaded. That means that `firstButton` will not be hooked up and it will be nil.

Comment: Yes my firstButton is an IBOutlet. How can I instantiate the cell not manually?

Comment: thanks for your interest in this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action methods you create new instances of CustomCell instead of referencing to the cell which holds the buttons. Try this code:

```
func buttonAction (sender: UIButton) {
    var cell = sender as UIView
    while (!cell.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell)) {
        cell = cell.superview!
    }

    if sender == cell.firstButton {
        // Do something when the first button was touched
    } else if sender == cell.secondButton {
        // Do something when the second button was touched
    }
}
```

Add this function as the action for both buttons.

Comment: if I use this I get: Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x38671380) to 'My_App.CustomCell' (0x508e98).

Comment: Then your buttons are not direct children of the cell. I will update my answer.